# Android Work Manager listen for clipboard data changed

Tags: android, worker, android-jetpack

This my first question on Stack Overflow. One my app, build for Instagram which works as tool for it. Whenever a user copies any text then I check to see if that text contains Instagram URL or not? If available then I parse it and then I do some cool stuff with it. Now my question is how can I do the same with using Worker to support it for all android versions.

If you need need more info tell me I will add it here

Comment: Welcome to posting on Stack Overflow. Please post the code associated with this question. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

> Now my question is how can I do the same with using Worker to support it for all android versions.

`WorkManager` will not work well here. It is designed to do things periodically, every 15+ minutes. It has no built-in abilities to respond to clipboard changes.

Comment: ohh thanks for informing about the same. Does Job Scheduler will help in my case ?

Comment: @Swapnil: No. `WorkManager` uses `JobScheduler`. It too is designed to do things periodically, every 15+ minutes.